# SQL-How to retrieve the correct data using php

Tags: php, sql

I am new to SQL so please excuse my question if it is simple.

I have a database with a few tables. 1 is a users table, the others are application tables that contain the users preferences for receiving notifications about that application based on the country they are interested in.

What I want to do, is retrieve the e-mail address of all users that have an interest in that country. I am struggling to think about how to do this. I currently have the following query constructed, and the code to populate the values

```
function check($string)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$string])) {
        $print = implode(', ', $_POST[$string]); //Converts an array into a single string
        $imanageSQLArr = Array();


        if (substr_count($print,'Benelux') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[0] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[0] = "off";


        }

        if (substr_count($print, 'France') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[1] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[1] = "off";

        }
        if (substr_count($print,  'Germany') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[2] = "checked";
        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[2] = "off";

        }
        if (substr_count($print,  'Italy') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[3] = "checked";
        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[3] = "off";

        }
        if (substr_count($print, 'Netherlands') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[4] = "checked";
        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[4] = "off";

        }
        if (substr_count($print,  'Portugal') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[5] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[5] = "off";
        }
        if (substr_count($print,  'Spain') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[6] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[6] = "off";
        }
        if (substr_count($print,  'Sweden') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[7] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[7] = "off";
        }
        if (substr_count($print,  'Switzerland') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[8] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[8] = "off";
        }

        if (substr_count($print, 'UK') > 0) {
            $imanageSQLArr[9] = "checked";

        } else {
            $imanageSQLArr[9] = "off";
        }
```

and the query

```
$tocheck = $db->prepare(
    "SELECT users.email
     FROM users,app
     WHERE users.id=app.userid
     AND BENELUX=:BENELUX
     AND FRANCE=:FRANCE
     AND GERMANY=:GERMANY
     AND ITALY=:ITALY
     AND NETHERLANDS=:NETHERLANDS
     AND PORTUGAL=:PORTUGAL
     AND SPAIN=:SPAIN
     AND SWEDEN=:SWEDEN
     AND SWITZERLAND=:SWITZERLAND
     AND UK=:UK");
$tocheck->execute($country);
$row = $tocheck->fetchAll();
```

This does retrieve data, but only people who's preferences match EXACTLY what is put (so what they haven't selected is taken into account as much as what they have). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND` (*my work is done*)

Comment: Will this not mean if the users "off" matches the "off" in the db though, it will return that user as a result? So it will always return every user?

Comment: @Programatt: Yes, the queries provided by Fred, Legionar and Rich will pull all records.

Comment: @Programatt:  See updated.  I gave you two possible solutions depending on exactly what you expect from your searching code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go one step further.  Basically, you have to see if the option is checked to see whether to actually test for that in your users.

For example:

```
SELECT email 
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN app a on (a.userid = u.id)
WHERE 
     (:BENELUX = 'off' OR a.BENELUX = :BENELUX)
AND (:FRANCE = 'off' OR a.FRANCE = :FRANCE)
```

etc..

What this does is limits the WHERE conditions down to just those that have your selected country.  However, if NO country is selected then ALL of the conditions will pass and you will get everyone.  So you probably want to have some checking in the PHP code to ensure that they picked at least one.

This line means allow the record if BENELUX was selected and the app table matches OR if benelux was not selected.

```
 (:BENELUX = 'off' OR a.BENELUX = :BENELUX)
```

The `and` here ensures that the previous condition must be true as well as this one.

```
AND (:FRANCE = 'off' OR a.FRANCE = :FRANCE)
```

Now, this is only going to pull all users which match **all** of the selected countries.  So if they are filtering on France **and** Benelux then only those users which have **both** France and Benelux attributes will be selected.

---

If you are trying to match any user that has **at least one** of the countries selected, then the query is slightly different:

```
SELECT email 
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN app a on (a.userid = u.id)
WHERE 
     (:BENELUX != 'off' AND a.BENELUX = :BENELUX)
OR (:FRANCE != 'off' AND a.FRANCE = :FRANCE)
```

Note that you don't have to do checking in PHP to ensure that they picked at least one country for this query.  If they picked nothing, then the query will return zero records.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you just need to change your AND's to OR's

```
$tocheck = $db->prepare(
"SELECT users.email
 FROM users,app
 WHERE users.id=app.userid
 AND 
(   
BENELUX=:BENELUX
 OR FRANCE=:FRANCE
 OR GERMANY=:GERMANY
 OR ITALY=:ITALY
 OR NETHERLANDS=:NETHERLANDS
 OR PORTUGAL=:PORTUGAL
 OR SPAIN=:SPAIN
 OR SWEDEN=:SWEDEN
 OR SWITZERLAND=:SWITZERLAND
 OR UK=:UK
)
");
$tocheck->execute($country);
$row = $tocheck->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks! but same as above:Will this not mean if the users "off" matches the "off" in the db though, it will return that user as a result? So it will always return every user?

Comment: Sorry, Chris's post wasn't live when I posted my answer.  Downvote probably not necessary :(

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I appreciate the help. Up voted you now to negate it :)